# Map DataTable to multiple Classes in C#

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, datatable

I have 3 Classes,

```
    public class DocumentMaster
    {
        public List<Category> Categories { get; set; }
    }
    public class Category
    {
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public List<Document> Documents { get; set; }
    }

    public class Document
    {
        public int DocumentId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentName { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
    }
```

I am getting DataTable from stored proc call, which gets collated data. I want to map that data to above classes.
Data Table has below columns

Id, CategoryId, CategoryName, DocumentId, DocumentName

Category 1 has 4 documents,Category 2 has 4 documents, category 3 has 3 documents, category 4 has 2 documents. All documents are unique. All document ids are unique.
Datatable data,

[DataTable Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cz5a7.png)

Need Linq query using lambda expressions to map this datatable to these classes.
Something like this,

```
      var list = dtDocuments.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(row => new DocumentMaster {
            Categories = new Category
            {
                CategoryId = row.Field<int>("CategoryId"),
                CategoryName = row.Field<string>("CategoryName"),
                Documents = new Document
                {
                    DocumentId = row.Field<int>("DocumentId"),
                    DocumentName = row.Field<string>("DocumentName"),
                    CategoryId = row.Field<int>("CategoryId")                        
                }
            }
        })
```

This is just one query. I am going to have multiple such tables and mappings to be done. Can someone please help with this query. I can take idea from this one, and write similar queries for other datatables that i have.

Comment: Maybe use some ORM like EF to map between the c# objects and the database tables? I think it will make it much easier for you

Comment: Using EF makes it easier, but I have multiple databases to connect to from one system. So can't use EF for that. This is one of the simple outputs from a combination of tables.

Comment: have you got solution for this ?